# .Jar File is not executing on double click on windows 7 (32 bit)

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

My `.jar` file is not executing on double click.

I have configured in `regedit`:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jarfile\shell\open\command and
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfile\shell\open\command
```

and selected

> Right Click →  Properties → Change → `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe`

But its not working.

It is working through the Command Line too. C:>java -jar JavaApplication1.jar

But not executing on Double Click

Comment: Have you checked the manifest file? Does it point to the right entry point?

Comment: No. How can I  do it?

Comment: "Right Click -> Properties -> Change -> C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" is *wrong*, it needs the -jar option.

Comment: Is it an executable jar?

Comment: Hasanka: a .jar file is not more than a .zip file with a different extension. unzip it, and check the manifest file.

Comment: Stultuske: I cant extract it any more.

Comment: Stultuske: got the MANIFEST.MF now wat can I do?

Comment: check, if there `Main-class: somePackage.SomeClass` attribute in it.

Comment: Dear All,  please note this .jar is working another windows 7 PC. bt it is 64 bit